# How to Enable Item-level language fallback on all templates in Sitecore 8.x

Tags: powershell-extensions, language-fallback

Presently I'm working on Sitecore 8.1 Update-1.

We have enabled Item-level language fallback on `shell` and `website` as suggested on [Configure language fallback - Sitecore Documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up__maintaining/language_fallback/setting_up/configure_language_fallback).

It seems after this we need to go to each template and enable the Item-level language fallback. It involves generating `__Standard Values` if its not there and then manually change the flag for item fallback *[screenshot below]*.

[image: Enable Item Fallback]

I have found this Sitecore PowerShell script on this [blog post](http://www.nttdatasitecore.com/Blog/2016/October/Enabling-Item-Level-Language-Fallback-Powershell-Script) which switches the Item-level fallback flag but here I will also require to generate `__Standard Values` on template.

```
(Get-Item master: -Query "/sitecore/templates//*[@@name='__Standard Values']")| ForEach-Object {

    $_.Editing.BeginEdit()
    $_.Fields["__Enable item fallback"].Value = "1";
    $_.Editing.EndEdit()
}
```

I'm trying on optimizing this process since same process has to be followed on multiple environments. How one can go for this with minimum impact/steps?

Comment: In regard to your update - changing standard items that come with Sitecore is a bad practice. Not only can you get problems when upgrading Sitecore version in the future, but also you're implementing item-level fallback for literally *all items in Sitecore*, including templates, layouts, etc. This may lead to unnecessary overhead, and even obscure errors, as changing that default value definitely has not been tested by Sitecore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that scripting this task is the way to go in your case.

Note that the script below doesn't update *all* templates' standard values, but only for templates under `User Defined`. If that doesn't suit you, feel free to adjust the path.

```powershell
$templates =
    Get-ChildItem 'master:/sitecore/templates/User Defined' -Recurse |
    ? { $_.TemplateId -eq '{AB86861A-6030-46C5-B394-E8F99E8B87DB}' }

foreach($template in $templates) {

    $standardValuesPath = "master:$($template.FullPath)/__Standard Values"

    if(Test-Path $standardValuesPath) {
        $standardValues = Get-Item $standardValuesPath
    } else {
        $standardValues = New-Item -Path $standardValuesPath -Type $template.ID
        $template.'__Standard values' = $standardValues.ID
    }

    $standardValues.'__Enable item fallback' = $true
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question now...

Comment: @HarshBaid Are you changing your question to something else now? Or would you like me to update something in my answer?

Comment: Question is still same.. just posted that one possibility other than PowerShell Scripting ;) but I think your point is correct about not modifying default Sitecore system items.

Comment: @Dmytro the PowerShell script is working perfectly fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I face similar situation before.

I approached this way:

As I inherit all my templates from "content" template, which is a custom empty template inherited from sitecore standard Template.

For me enabling item level fallback on "content" template __standardValues worked.

Comment: It does work. A great find! I wasn't aware of field-level inheritance between standard values.

Comment: Thanks @Dheeraj since I didn't wanted to introduce new template and anyways had to use PowerShell script one or other way for bulk operation to either update Fallback Field or Base Template Field ( if I had used concept in your answer) . I have used the PowerShell script provided by Dmytro for this instance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as one of the possibility, To update the Default Value on Sitecore field definition of `__Enable item fallback` located here - `/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections/Advanced/Advanced/__Enable item fallback` *[screenshot below]* as I wanted Item-level fallback to happen for all items:

[image: __Enable item fallback]

Note: It is Sitecore best practice that we better not update system templates.